# SOAP request envelope not generating correctly in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a SOAP request and have tried using both `SoapClient` and `Zend\Soap\Client`, but I just can't seem to get it to build up correctly. Here's the envelope as it is supposed to look:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
   xmlns:imag="http://custom-url-here">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Logon>
         <tem:request>
            <imag:Password>XXXXXXXX</imag:Password>
            <imag:User>XXXXXXXX</imag:User>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:Logon>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm not experienced with SOAP (REST & JSON kicks its ass, but anyway), but here's what I've managed so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns:ns2="custom-url-here">

    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:imag/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>

    <ns1:Logon>
        <request>
            <Password>XXXXXX</Password>
            <User>XXXXXXX</User>
        </request>
    </ns1:Logon>

    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see, it's wrong, but it's getting there. Here's the code I used:

```
$wsdl = 'http://url-of-wsdl';
$namespace = 'http://custom-url-here';

$client = new Client($wsdl);
$client->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_1);

$header = new \SoapHeader($namespace, 'imag');
$client->addSoapInputHeader($header);

$params = [
    new \SoapVar([
        new \SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, null, $namespace, 'Password'),
        new \SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, $namespace, 'User'),
     ], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $namespace, 'request'),
];
$result = $client->Logon(new SoapVar($params, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

Can someone point out what i have done wrong? As I say, I usually work with JSON REST interfaces, so there could be several things wrong with this!
Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to get it to return the response I needed! I changed these lines:

```
$params = [
            new \SoapVar([
                new \SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'ns2:Password'),
                new \SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'ns2:User'),
            ], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'ns1:request'),
        ];
```

It works, but the generated envelope still doesn't look like the original, so this isn't the best answer, and if anyone can explain how to get it identical I will be very happy!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://my-custom-url">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:imag/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:Logon>
            <ns1:request>
                <ns2:Password>XXXXXX</ns2:Password>
                <ns2:User>XXXXXX</ns2:User>
            </ns1:request>
        </ns1:Logon>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```